# Youtube API subscription failing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My issue is trying to pinpoint exactly what i need to do to be able to add a subscription to a user.

I have these scripts added to my html

```
<!-- Youtube platform start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

My script is as follows:

```
            // Get browser location
            $scope.currentUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;

            // get Channel Id
            var channelId = CHANNEL_ID_HERE;

            // Call to Youtube API for channel thumbnail, name, description, and subscribers
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics,snippet&id=' + channelId + '&key={API_KEY}'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.channelThumbnail = response.data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                $scope.channelName = response.data.items[0].snippet.title;
                $scope.channelDesc = response.data.items[0].snippet.description;
                $scope.channelSubs = response.data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

            function initClient() {
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: 'API_KEY',
                    clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
                    scope: 'profile',
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("gapi initialized");
                });
            }

            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', initClient);

            $scope.addSubscription = function () {
                var resource = {
                    part: 'snippet',
                    snippet: {
                        resourceId: {
                            kind: 'youtube#channel',
                            channelId: channelId
                        }
                    }
                };
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.insert(resource);
                request.execute(function (response) {
                        var result = response.result;
                        if (result) {
                            alert("Subscription completed");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Subscripion failed");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
```

Please pretend the clientID and ApiKeys are in there. When I call my addSubscription function, this is the call that is sent out: https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&alt=json&key=APIKEY. Am I not initializing something properly or is there something else that's needed to complete this POST? I've read through a lot of documentation but can't seem to find the reason this won't succeed. My GET requests are working great, but i can't seem to get a POST request to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the response that you get?

Comment: The response is 401

Comment: You say you're POST method is not working but your posted code is using GET. Did you try looking at this [Youtube API erros list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)? Look at error 401 guidelines.